# How to ignore key unprotect errors

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

My application often fails with failed to unprotect session cookie (I am using two applications with different assembly versions).

> Error unprotecting the session cookie. The key {hex_key} was not found in the key ring.

or

> System.InvalidOperationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {hex_key} was not found in the key ring.

Antiforgery errors happen at get requests (so nothing to be protected there). How can I ignore such errors and display page for users (with new session)?

Comment: I have the same problem. It's absolutely flooding my logs and causing my app to crash. Did you manage to get to the bottom of this?